# C# WPF Create function that creats new inputs

Tags: c#

I am using C# Wpf and i would like to create a function that once you click on a button A new Textbox will appear is this possible and I want to know if it possible to increase the form hight when a new Textbox is created

Answer (score 0):

The question isnt exactly specific but yes you can make new UI elements in the code-behind. In WPF you would put your button on the window, then add the "Click" event to it. Then in the click event you could code something like. . .

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button newButton = new Button();    //Create a new button control and assign it to newButton
    newButton.Width = 35;   //Access fields like this (You can access any of the ones you access from the Xaml user interface)
    newButton.Height = 20;
    newButton.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    newButton.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
    newButton.Content = "click me!";

    grMain.Children.Add(newButton); //Add it to the grid
}
```

grMain is the name of my grid, make sure you name it and call it by the name. You can also call other elements, such as a stack panel or whatever you need. So for your case just make it a textbox instead of a button

Oops didnt see the second part of your question! To resize the window you need to first add a name to it in the XAML (Like you would name a grid or button - just name the window something). And just as we called grMain in my example call that and change the height/width properties.

Comment: Thanks for you help fivestart, I did what you did please check my answer, I hope you can help me again

Comment: @arclite86 It is best to actually edit your original post instead of posting another answer to modify your question. But thats okay for now. You see how you added the x:name to your button? You can do that to the grid as well and the window. So like <Window x:Name="myWindow" . . .>. And for your grid you need something like. <Grid x:Name "grMain"> </Grid>

Comment: Ok , i finally got it, I have now created a new button in my stackpanel, but how can i add multiple buttons and inputs in the same row?